# firestore, firecloud unsafe or uncheck operations. What does it even mean?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, development-environment

Why is it showing this error, even my minimumSdkVersion is set on 21
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhb8I.png)